# text node and childnodes

Tags: javascript

I was reading about `textNodes` and `childnodes` on the internet. I read much about the nodes but i did get it understand. What are `textnodes` exactly?

I have a sample HTML and i want to know what are the `textNode`s of my divs and how to pick `childnodes` and `textnodes`.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(document.childNodes[1].childNodes[0])
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv">
        <div>abc</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: please could you rephrase your question?

Comment: Not clear on your question really, but for a list of node types see MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType

Comment: how to alert textnodes , that is my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The entire document is a document node
- Every HTML element is an element node
- The text in the HTML elements are text nodes
- Every HTML attribute is an attribute node
- Comments are comment nodes

Comment: to add to that, [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.childNodes) are direct descendants of element nodes

Comment: You select the element node containing the textnode you want to alert, and alert its innerHTML